Oxygen/HTTP - I have a problem with CORS handling
On Windows Server 2022 I have an API that is based on Julia. Everything works fine except CORS handling. I have the following code:
using Oxygen
using HTTP

...

function CorsMiddleware(handler)
    return function(req::HTTP.Request)
        println("CORS middleware")
        
        # Log the request headers
        println("Request Headers -> ", req.headers)
        
        # Handle preflight requests (OPTIONS)
        if HTTP.method(req) == "OPTIONS"
            return HTTP.Response(200, "Preflight response")
        else
            try
                # Call the next handler
                res = handler(req)
                
                # Log the response body
                println("CorsMiddleware: Response Body -> ", res.body)
                
                # Return a basic response without headers
                return HTTP.Response(res.status, res.body)
            catch e
                println("Error in CorsMiddleware when calling handler(req): ", e)
                return HTTP.Response(500, "Internal Server Error")
            end
        end
    end
end

function AuthMiddleware(handler)
    return function(req::HTTP.Messages.Request)
        println("Auth middleware")
        
        try
            # Call the next handler
            res = handler(req)
            
            # Log the response body
            println("AuthMiddleware: Response Body -> ", res.body)
            
            # Return a basic response without any headers
            return HTTP.Response(res.status, res.body)
        catch e
            println("Error in AuthMiddleware when calling handler(req): ", e)
            return HTTP.Response(500, "Internal Server Error")
        end
    end
end

...

serve(port=4091, middleware=[CorsMiddleware, AuthMiddleware])

I added the println statements to see why things don't work. This is the output:
CORS middleware
Request Headers -> Pair{SubString{String}, 
SubString{String}}["Host" => "localhost:4091", 
"User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:131.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/131.0", "Accept" => "*/*", 
"Accept-Language" => "en-US,en;q=0.5", 
"Accept-Encoding" => "gzip, deflate, br, zstd", 
"Content-Type" => "text/plain", "Content-Length" => "22", 
"Origin" => "https://viewer.trexyz.net", 
"Connection" => "keep-alive", 
"Sec-Fetch-Dest" => "empty", 
"Sec-Fetch-Mode" => "cors", 
"Sec-Fetch-Site" => "cross-site", 
"Priority" => "u=4"]

Auth middleware
AuthMiddleware: Response Body -> UInt8[0x5b, 0x22, 0x4d, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x73, 0x5f, 0x32, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x4b, 0x69, 0x70, 0x70, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x5f, 0x42, 0x22, 0x2c, 0x22, 0x4b, 0x69, 0x70, 0x70, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x5f, 0x41, 0x22, 0x5d]
Error in AuthMiddleware when calling handler(req): ArgumentError("invalid header key-value pair: 91")
CorsMiddleware: Response Body -> UInt8[0x49, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x65, 0x72, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x20, 0x53, 0x65, 0x72, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x45, 0x72, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x72]
Error in CorsMiddleware when calling handler(req): ArgumentError("invalid header key-value pair: 73")

The invalid header errors keep coming, no matter what I try - like stricter header handling, and using hardcoded headers. Even a completely stripped test like this gives a 500 error:
using HTTP

function simple_handler(req::HTTP.Request)
    println("Simple handler")
    
    # Create a basic response body
    response_body = "{\"message\": \"Hello, world!\"}"
    
    # Return a basic response without headers
    return HTTP.Response(200, response_body)

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here?

I think there is an invalid character problem. Character 91 corresponds to the opening square bracket [ and character 73 is capital i (I). These could indicate issues with how the response body or headers are being processed. Specifically, you're logging and returning UInt8[] arrays directly, which might be misinterpreted. You might need to ensure proper string conversions and the header contains the key-pair values accurately.

@burcu, since the simple_handler doesn't process headers but also gives an error, does that mean an error in the response is most likely?

In the CorsMiddleware and AuthMiddleware, you should ensure that when you return a response, it contains valid headers and a properly formatted body. Also, use Dict for headers and ensure the values are well-formed strings.
Additionally, in your simple_handler, ensure that you return a String body as well.

With your comments and a little (lot... :- ) help from ChatGPT I have a properly working version of a "simple_handler" that I can use to build on. Thank you for your help!

pls update your question with the proper solution or post an answer and accept it as a solution so that in the future when people come across this issue, they can solve it. happy coding!
